# WP7 foreach loop to a datalist

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, datalist

I have several foreach loops after each other in a larger foreach loop.. What I'm wanting to do is to add each set of passes into a datalist/datasource.

```
foreach (HtmlNode cell in cells3)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textBlock4.Text = cell.InnerText);
}

foreach (HtmlNode cell in cells)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textBlock5.Text = cell.InnerText);
}

foreach (HtmlNode cell in cells2)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textBlock6.Text = cell.InnerText);
}
```

My current code goes through and dumps the results to the textblocks but it over-rights each other so it only displays the last result. So somehow I need to add them to variables or a datalist to display them separately in a list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the text like this:

```
textBlock4.Text = cell.InnerText
```

you could *append* it, like this:

```
textBlock4.Text += cell.InnerText
```

A better (and faster, as it doesn't use the slow DependencyProperty system as excessive as well as relieves the dispatcher) approach would be aggregating the text in a `StringBuilder` and assigning it afterwards, like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (HtmlNode cell in cells3)
{
    sb.AppendLine(cell.InnerText);
}
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textBlock4.Text = sb.ToString());
sb.Clear();

// reuse sb for the following loops as shown above
```

You could also use LINQ, which would make the whole thing a little shorter:

```
StringBuilder sb = cells3.Aggregate(
    new StringBuilder(),
    (sb, cell) => sb.AppendLine(cell.InnerText));

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textBlock4.Text = sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks @Tobias, The appending bit was alot of help but I'm still unsure on how to display them all in a list format, for instance I have the results in a list but, originally it over-rite the results but now it appends in a straight row of text.. I need to cut it up into sections do display underneath eachother

Comment: For that you could, for example, append a number of `Environment.NewLine`s to the string (or, if you use the `StringBuilder`, call `AppendLine` again)...